# PHP While Value with headline but headline also showing multiple time

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a location PHP database and i'm getting datausing mysqli connection like that

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

$sql = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM location');
```

And i'm using while for print my value like

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($result['locationvalue'] > 1 && $result['locationvalue'] < 2){
            echo '<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">';
            echo '<option value="'.$result["locationvalue"].'"  >'.$result["locationname"].'</option>';
            echo '</optgroup>';
        }elseif($result['locationvalue'] > 1 && $result['locationvalue'] < 3){
            echo '<optgroup label="Arunachal Pradesh">';
            echo '<option value="'.$result["locationvalue"].'"  >'.$result["locationname"].'</option>';
            echo '</optgroup>';
        }
    }
}
```

This Code helping me to get data but there is a issue i'm also want headline in this code. when i run this code its look like

```
Andhra Pradesh
Anantapur

Andhra Pradesh
Guntakal

Andhra Pradesh
Guntur

Arunachal Pradesh
Bayana

Arunachal Pradesh
Bharatpur
```

**But I Want Like that**

```
<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">
    <option value="Anantapur"  >Anantapur</option>
    <option value="Guntakal"  >Guntakal</option>
    <option value="Guntur"  >Guntur</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Arunachal Pradesh">
    <option value="Bayana"  >Bayana</option>
    <option value="Bharatpur"  >Bharatpur</option>
    <option value="Guntur"  >Guntur</option>
</optgroup>
```

please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

### Update your code like shown below

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){

    $result = $sql->fetch_assoc();

    echo '<optgroup label="$result[0]["locationvalue"]">';

    while($result) {

        if($result['locationvalue'] > 1 && $result['locationvalue'] < 2){
            echo '<option value="'.$result["locationvalue"].'"  >'.$result["locationname"].'</option>';
            echo '</optgroup>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have more then one Option then what i do

Answer (score 0):

move the `echo '<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">'` from the while

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
  echo '<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">';
    while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($result['locationvalue'] > 1 && $result['locationvalue'] < 2){                
            echo '<option value="'.$result["locationvalue"].'"  >'.$result["locationname"].'</option>';                
        }
       echo '</optgroup>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have more then one Option then what i do

Comment: move the both option out of the whole loop

Comment: what your trying to achieve can you add your $result array

Comment: add your $result array to the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the optgroup code outside the while array .

```
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    echo '<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">';
while($result = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($result['locationvalue'] > 1 && $result['locationvalue'] < 2){
        echo '<option value="'.$result["locationvalue"].'"  >'.$result["locationname"].'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I have more then one Option then what i do